# Jetpack Compose: Find how many lines a text will take before composition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to determine how many lines a certain text will occupy on the screen before composition. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `onTextLayout` on `Text` to get line count and some other features.

```
var lineCount = 1
Text(text= "", onTextLayout = {textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
    lineCount = textLayoutResult.lineCount
})
```

If you are using Jetpack Compose version 1.4.1 or above you can use
TextMeasurer to measure text with any style you provide

```
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

    val textToDraw = "Some text to measure\nSomething something"

    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 150.sp,
        color = Color.Black,
        background = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
    )

    // You can get many information since it's TextLayoutResult as in callback
    val textLayoutResult = remember(textToDraw) {
        textMeasurer.measure(textToDraw, style)
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is TextLayoutResult set after layout/composition?

Comment: I used it to send this value to child to after determining text length and line count and had no issue. But best way to test is setting log in onTextLayout, `Modifier.layout{}` and `Modifier.drawWithContent` or `Modifier.drawBehind{}` to see in which order values or phases are set

Comment: This always returns 1 for me. It is because `measure` method takes `Constraint` and its `maxWidth` is set to `Infinity`. By changing `maxWidth` to text's width, I was able to calculate line count.

Comment: Working. Excellent

Comment: With second one if your Constraints do not match your Tect composable you won't get correct result. In that case change Constraints too

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer is correct there is an alternative way, which doesn't even require a Composable function:

```
val paragraph = androidx.compose.ui.text.Paragraph(
    text = "Foo",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
    constraints = Constraints(maxWidth = maxWidthInPx),
    density = LocalDensity.current,
    fontFamilyResolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current,
)
paragraph.lineCount
```

This might be better suited if it's required to know the lineCount beforehand.

Comment: How did you compute maxWidthInPx?

Comment: You'll have to know somehow, since this is can happen outside a Composable function. It depends on your usecase. You could use `maxWidth` within a `BoxWithConstraints`. Or simply the device width with the paddings you use.